# ¿Por qué los valientes tienen "los huevos cuadrados"?

Tags: coloquialismos, expresiones

Es fácil entender la asociación de los órganos sexuales masculinos con el valor. Así, si queremos decir que alguien es muy valiente podemos decir coloquialmente que tiene los "huevos" (o *cojones*)

- Muy grandes
- Bien puestos
- De acero
- etc.

Es simple. Todas esas referencias hacen relación a la "calidad" del órgano, que se refleja figurativamente en la cuantía del valor.

Ahora, que la forma también tiene que ver, ya es mucho más abstracto. Sin embargo, para indicar que alguien es valiente se puede decir que tiene "los huevos **cuadrados**".

¿Por qué esta peculiar (y nada natural) forma se asocia con el valor?

Comment: ¿Dónde se usa esta frase? Qué gracioso.

Comment: @Rodrigo es común al menos en España. No sé seguro si se usa en otros países de habla hispana.

Comment: Cuadrado = squared (in the mathematical sense). In English at least it is often used to emphasise what preceded it.

Comment: Porque las redondas rollarían......

Answer (score 9):

No se refiere a la forma, sino a que "los tiene bien puestos" o "en su sitio". Cuando algo encaja bien en algún lugar, se dice que "cuadra perfectamente", pues es fácil que algo de forma cuadrada encaje bien.

Por eso, se refiere a que se le dan bien la condición de hombre, pues los genitales, símbolo de su valor, le cuadran perfectamente

Comment: No sé si esta respuesta estará acreditada, pero desde luego a mí me cuadra totalmente...

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Algo así. Está explicado en términos generales para su entendimiento en el sitio. Por ello, +1.

Comment: No lo sé a ciencia cierta, pero ¿no podría ser que la expresión se use para referirse a alguien que tiene un coraje particularmente inusual, tan inusual como sería tener gónadas cuadradas?

Answer (score 1):

En mi casa se utiliza pero no con un sentido positivo.

Tiene más que ver con holgazanería, obcecarse con hacer algo incorrecto. Por ejemplo:

> "anda que estar tirado en el sofá todo el día y no ser capaz ni de tirar la basura... Tienes los cojones cuadrados!".

Yo lo asocio con una deformación de la expresión "tener la cabeza cuadrada", pero refiriéndose a algo negativo.

Answer (score 1):

Yo me inclino por [la teoria de @Saul](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17825/1674). Deriva de la colocación ser de "cabeza cuadrada", o sea, duro de mollera o cuadriculado.

El significado metafórico del adjetivo vendrá de la exactitud de una cuadricula donde se realizan medidas con mucha precisión. De igual forma, se puede ver cómo ser un "cabezón" (tener la cabeza grande), es sinónimo de testarudo. La misma imagen se usa con los huevos/cojones: tenerlos bien grandes. Al final, son construcciones metáforicas que transfieren cualidades de pesadez y rigidez.

[@Giancarlo Ventura hace alusión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17235/1674) a que esta construcción se relaciona con que "algo cuadre bien", haciendo alusión a que el valor (sus cojones) encaja en el cuerpo del hombre. Sin embargo, yo creo que esa relación está del todo clara. Que algo cuadre sigue compartiendo el significado de que encaja en una cuadricula porque sus proporciones son adecuadas, como menciono antes, queriendo decir que algo se ajusta a nuestras expectativas.

El "tenerlos bien puestos" más bien diría que surge de otra metáfora: las cosas inamovibles representan determinación, saber estar, control, etc. De ahí que [*puesto*](https://dle.rae.es/puesto) tenga las siguientes acepciones según el DLE:

> 1. adj. Resuelto, empeñado, determinado.
> 12. m. Estado o disposición en que se halla una cosa, física o moralmente.

Existen otras expresiones en castellano que beben de esta misma metáfora: mantenerse en sus trece, sacar a alguien de sus casillas... También se dice "no hay quien lo mueva", "no hay quien lo saque" cuando alguien no cede a cambiar de parecer. Por eso, veo más factible que "tenerlos bien puestos" tenga que ver esto mismo, y no con ideas de valentía. Más bien, tener unas ideas fijas que por nada del mundo vas a cambiar.